# Remove or disabled one of the wordpress Widget Class

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I have one tiny issue with a layout on the Widget class, I have 5 same widgets, but one of the widgets is having an issue with the video clip,

I have a look into browser developer mode and found the issue 
(please see red highlight box on the screenshot)

[image]

```
<div id="shapely_home_parallax-20" class="widget shapely_home_parallax">        <section class=" border-bottom">

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center mt30">
<div class="">
<div class="mb32">
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 text-center mb-xs-24">

<iframe>I remove all iframe for youtube</iframe></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1
text-left"></p>
<h3>User Friendly with Easy Installation</h3>
<p>We designed our range of adaptable flood barriers with our clients in mind. With a simple installation, almost anyone can secure their home or business against floods and water damage. Thanks to the customisable width and two variations of securing mechanisms, our flood barriers will ensure your investments remain safely sealed.
</p></div>
</div>                              </div>
</div>
<!--end of row-->
```

I tried to find a way to disable this section only

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center mt30">
```

or change into

```
<div class="text-center">
```

but nothing working

I just want to fix one widget but not all, I have tried it on additional CSS in wordpress but seems it's not working.

any example or similar issue something would be great.

Comment: you want to remove class only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove those class using Jquery.

```
jQuery('#shapely_home_parallax-20 .mt30').removeClass("col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 mt30");
```

You just have unique div id with reference of that you can remove that classes.

**Where to put :**

You can put code inside footer file before `wp_footer()` function. If there is no  tag then you should put inside tag.

Answer (score 0):

@Vasim

Thank you so much

It's Working fine but I didn't put into the footer files as I am not a fan of putting anything on PHP files due to update themes or etc.

I have put it on the code in WordPress snippet

```
<?php
function script_widget_CSS_remove(){ ?>

<script>
jQuery('#shapely_home_parallax-20 .mt30').removeClass("col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 mt30");
</script>

<?php } 

add_action('wp_footer', 'script_widget_CSS_remove');
```

and it working fine